# Resource Management Design Patterns

Tags: c++, design-patterns, raii

Various APIs require calls to initialization and finalization methods. Most recently I've come across this while using the Python C++ API, where all API calls must be between calls to `Py_Initialize` and `Py_FinalizeEx`. My current solution is to put such calls at the beginning and end of the main method. This does not seem ideal, as it separates the actual usage of the API from it's resource management. That is, the software components which make API calls rely on the main method to acquire and destroy the resources.

Is there a pattern that is usually applied in such a scenario?

Here is what I'm currently doing.

```
int redirected(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Actual main method

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program)
        Py_SetProgramName(program);
    else
        throw new std::runtime_error("Py_SetProgramName");

    Py_Initialize();

    int errc = redirected(argc, argv);

    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0)
        throw new std::runtime_error("Py_FinalizeEx");

    PyMem_RawFree(program);

    return errc;
}
```

Comment: can u add a code sample how you tried to implement thus case?

Comment: @LiorBar-On I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper pattern in C++ is using RAII. And indeed, it's a very good question.

This means that the constructor of an object will acquire the resource and the destructor will release it. This way you ensure that the resource will always be freed when you get out of scope.

For Python, it would be:

```
class PyInit
{
public:
    PyInit() {Py_Initialize();}
    ~PyInit() {Py_Finalize();}
}
```

And then in main:

```
int main()
{
    PyInit pyinit;
    // using Python interpreter
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here, I'd let the lifetime of the object determine the lifetime of the API, which is quite similar to what one would already do while just using the calls directly. The solution which I see as more optimal would have every object that like to use an API, make sure that it'll either initialize or destroy the resources when it's the first or last one to use the API.

Comment: You could use a shared pointer on the RAII object and share it with all the objects that could extend the life of the resource.